# Override Parent Theme Function in Child Theme? How?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, overriding

I want to change the output in this function.

```
function ph_mailchimp($action){
    $msg = get_theme_mod('pic_mailchimp', 'text');
    $output = '
    <div class="newsletter-box well">
      <p>' . $msg  . '</p>
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="'.$action.'" class="new_subscriber" data-remote="true" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" method="post">
        <div style="display:none">
          <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="">
        </div>
        <input class="inputfield" id="mce-EMAIL" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Your email" type="email">
        <input name="subscribe" type="submit" value="Subscribe">
      </form>
    </div>';
    return $output;
}
```

Basically I want to add a code in my Child theme's `functions.php` file to override the Output in the function above.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: How is that function hooked into WordPress? Under which action hook?

Comment: There is no add_action line for this function in the file. The function name ph_mailchimp is mentioned only in the code above. That's it.

Comment: Where is it called? In a template? Can't you just override the template to change the function name?

Comment: It's the main functions.php file in my Wordpress theme. I can't override it. It must be done with filters & hooks i believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can, if you have the proper setup.  Install APD from PECL, or runkit from the same.  If you have runkit, this should do the trick:

```
runkit_function_remove ( "ph_mailchimp" );

function ph_mailchimp() {
    echo "Foobar";//do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Just a note...if the function is hooked via a WordPress Action hook, the OP won't need APD or runkit. Otherwise, this is a fine option.

Comment: The function I added in the OP is the one from the Parent Theme's functions.php file. What i want is to override the output somehow in the Child theme.

Comment: Basically I want to have a different form displayed on the site, instead of  the one in the function.

Comment: See mevius' note here.  I don't know off the top of my head if that action is hooked, but since you're testing (I assume), I'd try just over-writing the function and seeing if it blows up.  If it doesn't, you win, and if it does, try APD or runkit.

And if that fails, there's always the possibility of a JS hack :P

Comment: I'm not a programmer so i have no idea how to get started with APD or runkit. Anyway, there must be a way to overwrite the function in the child theme. How do people overwrite functions from main theme usually? Can anyone help?

Comment: The PHP manual notes well, "PHP does not support function overloading, nor is it possible to undefine or redefine previously-declared functions."

So it's not possible to do, apart from editing the installation's main functions.php file.  The only way to do it is to install one of the extensions mentioned and use those functions, else you'll get a fatal error.  

The alternative then, is to hack out the "bad" function from functions.php and replace it either in that file or another included file.  You'll have to do this each time you update your WP installation though ... possibly a real PITA.